# Display path in one line, no element wrapping

Tags: html, css

I need to have a div element with `div`s and `search-item`s display in one line, the `div`s will contain folder names and splits (\) and `search-item` will contain the path to that folder.

Somehow looking like this:

`\ Some \ path`

The structure looks like this:

```css
/* Search */
.app.searchbar.object {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  float: left;
  word-wrap: none;
  word-break: none;
  display: block;
}

.app.searchbar.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.app.searchbar.item:hover {
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.app.searchbar.split {}
.app.searchbar.split::before {
  content: '\\';
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="app searchbar object">
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="0">A</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="1">Very</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="2">Special</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="3">Path</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="4">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="5">Contains</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="6">Hidden</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="7">Files</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="8">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="9">Can</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="10">Ruin</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="11">Your</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="12">Life</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="13">So</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="14">Much</search-item>
</div>
```

When you run the snippet you see that it gets out of the line, while I want it to get everything in one line hiding under the padding.

Also scrolling down will result in scrolling right. But the scroll bar is not supposed to show.

Comment: So you just want hiding in case of overflow, yes?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to scrolldown will be scroll right

Comment: I don't understand how scrolldown would look like in this case, for example `overflow: hidden` can just hide overflowing entries.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/pwmyaV and to make the vertical scroll a horizontal scroll instead, use https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

Comment: I don't want it to exceed a width over 100% because that will ruin how my app works like....

Answer (score 0):

You can add `width: 900px;` (or any fixed width that fits you, but it hads to be fixed) and `overflow-x:visible;` to `.app.searchbar.object`, and delete the float in there:

```css
/* Search */
.app.searchbar.object {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  word-wrap: none;
  word-break: none;
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  overflow-x:visible;
}

.app.searchbar.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
 float:left;
}

.app.searchbar.item:hover {
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.app.searchbar.split {}
.app.searchbar.split::before {
  content: '\\';
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="app searchbar object">
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="0">A</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="1">Very</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="2">Special</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="3">Path</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="4">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="5">Contains</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="6">Hidden</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="7">Files</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="8">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="9">Can</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="10">Ruin</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="11">Your</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="12">Life</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="13">So</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="14">Much</search-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;` to `.app.searchbar.object` and use display:inline-block for `.item' and`.split`. seems to do it.

```css
/* Search */
.app.searchbar.object {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.app.searchbar.split{
   display: inline-block;
}
.app.searchbar.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.app.searchbar.item:hover {
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.app.searchbar.split {}
.app.searchbar.split::before {
  content: '\\';
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

```html
<div class="app searchbar object">
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="0">A</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="1">Very</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="2">Special</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="3">Path</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="4">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="5">Contains</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="6">Hidden</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="7">Files</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="8">That</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="9">Can</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="10">Ruin</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="11">Your</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="12">Life</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="13">So</search-item>
  <div class="app searchbar split"></div>
  <search-item class="app searchbar item" item="14">Much</search-item>
</div>
```